# "The "path" argument must be string. Received undefined"how do I resolve this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, path, node-modules

In my project that I developed with node js, I get the error "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be string. Received undefined". Can you help me?

some of the codes:

```
router.post('/test', (req,res) =>{

   const post_image = req.files.post_image.name

   post_image.mv(path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/img/postimages', post_image.name))

   Post.create(req.body)
   console.log(req.files.post_image.name)
   res.redirect("/")
})
```

I think the error may be caused by the code in third line because when you make it a comment line, the error disappears.

Comment: You are reading `name` property of `post_image.name`, basically `name.name`. This must be the `undefined` value. You probably need to pass `post_image` instead of `post_image.name`.

Answer (score 1):

`_dirname` or `post_image.name` must be undefined. Check all the arguments of `path.resolve()` function are defined and string

Comment: post_image tanımlı 3. satırı yorum satırı yapıp cosnole logun içine post_iamge yazdığım zaman çalışıyor. dirname kısmını anlayamadım hocam

Comment: post_image, post_image.name ve __dirname hepsini bir logla hepsinin tanımlı gelmesi lazım birinde sikinti var muhtemelen.

Comment: evet dirname i console log ladığım zaman aynı hatayı alıyorum, nasıl tanımlayabilirim dirname i?

Comment: import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'
import { dirname } from 'path'
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
const __dirname = dirname(__filename). bunu dene bi https://www.kindacode.com/article/node-js-using-__dirname-and-__filename-with-es-modules/

Comment: import ederken hata alıyorum olmuyor bu da.

Comment: knk import yerine require kullanmayı denesene. const {fileURLToPath} = require('url') seklinde